# How to sign messages using the NOISE Protocol Framework?

Tags: encryption, signature, key-exchange, decryption, noise-protocol

I wanted to learn more about secure messaging and started a personal project using the `libhydrogen` library. From my understanding, instead of using public-key encryption, the library relies on the noise protocol framework to create ephemeral session keys shared by both parties to encrypt and decrypt messages. I was wondering if the same session keys can be used to sign and verify the messages, or should this better be done with another (not shared) key pair? Also, I couldn't find any information on how long these session keys should last. Are they intended to be used for several days, weeks, or longer, or should I think of a session key as a login to an online service that expires after 10-15min, unless you stay active?

As I said, I am new to the topic and there might be very straightforward answers. Unfortunately, I couldn't find this information myself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need signatures, use [the signatures API](https://github.com/jedisct1/libhydrogen/wiki/Public-key-signatures). Signing key pairs may or may not be ephemeral, this depends on your use case. You'll need some way to determine that a signing keypair belongs to whoever you think it belongs to, this can't be handled by the library alone.

Signing key pairs and key exchange key pairs are different data types (`hydro_sign_keypair` vs `hydro_kx_keypair` or `hydro_kx_session_keypair`) and thus can't be used interchangeably.

A session should last at most for as long as a given connection using the service lasts. That might be weeks, but is more likely only as long as a user stays active.